# Merge two datasets of different lengths, R

Tags: r, merge

I have an issue merging two datasets of different lengths - below are some examples

df1:

```
A B C D  E  F
1 1 1 10 20 3
1 1 1 10 20 2
1 1 1 15 10 1
1 1 1 20 15 3
1 2 1 10 20 3
1 2 1 15 10 3
2 1 1 20 20 3
2 1 1 30 10 1
2 2 1 50 10 2
```

df2:

```
A B C X  Y  Z
1 1 1 10 10 1
1 2 1 20 20 2
2 1 1 10 20 1
2 2 1 20 20 2
```

I need to create a new dataframe where I incorporate `df2$X` and `df2$Y` into df1 for each grouping variable (A and B).

I have tried the following:

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1, all.y = TRUE)
```

This works as far `df3$X` and `df3$Y` are concerned, however the ordering of `df3$D` and `df3$E` is slightly wrong.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can keep the ordering for these variables correct as they first appear in df1?

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems like you may just want to duplicate a few rows.

Answer (score 2):

When using merge, it might be a good idea to specify a key with the following

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1, by="your key", all.y=T)
```

but as it has been said a reproducible example would help